# Fetch n nodes matching attribute condition in xml file using XPATH

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xpath

Using xpath how do i fetch 10 nodes(actually it may be n nodes where n is a integer) from a xml file matching attribute condition. For example below query is fine but just does fetch like the `TOP statement` in Sql server.

`Codes/QualityCode[position() < 10][@Status=1]`

#### Input

```
<Codes>
  <Code Code="6837266077" Status="0" />
  <Code Code="6752266017" Status="1" />
  <Code Code="6457266097" Status="0" />
  <Code Code="6316005722" Status="1" />
....
</Codes>
```

Comment: What do you want if you don't want TOP ?  How do you want to limit the nodes to `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change your xpath around, that is first filter on the Status followed by a filter on the position like

```
Codes/QualityCode[@Status=1][position() < 10]
```

Comment: Yup that worked like it should. Developers need to train their brains more than the language they work in. Thanks